# Win32 DLL / Reference storing

Tags: c, memory-management, dll

I've been given the task to create a DLL with a lot of functions. The specific implementation of the functions is actually quite easy but the general (or better: initial) setup gives me a headache and I wasn't able to make sense of it yet. So here are two (of the many) functions I am supposed to implement:

```
long initClient(long* client, char* a = "", char* b = "");
long clientSet(int client, const char* a, const char* b);
```

The first function will setup a client (there can be 0..n, each client has internal state data), so somehow it will need to keep track of the client related data internally. Now whenever I call clientSet (the second function) I need to pass the integer value (long* client) I get from initClient to the function so it can identify the correct client data structure and change that very data.

The actual question now is: How do I do this correctly?

My current solution would be to hold an internal list of clients with their associated data/ID and use malloc/free whenever a client is added or removed. Yet, I have the feeling that this is not a clean solution or that it could be solved in a better way.

Your help is highly appreciated.

EDIT: After re-thinking it, could it be that the first parameter of clientSet is actually the pointer I get from initClient (first parameter)? If this was the case, initClient would only need to malloc some memory and fill that with data. All other calls would then only reference that memory area. Yet, I find it highly troublesome to use different data types for the same pointer (I get a pointer to a long which I then need to interpret as int - i understand that both of them are 4 byte on Win32). Am I right here?

EDIT #2: Unfortunately I am not allowed to change the interface in any way.

EDIT #3: After more thinking about this problem, maybe this is what I am actually after:

```
intptr_t my_ptr;

long initClient(intptr_t* client, char* a, char* b);
long clientSet(intptr_t client, char* a, char* b);
```

initClient(&my_ptr, "A", "B") would basically (I will need to see how to do the de-referencing correctly) do a

```
*client = (intptr_t)malloc(sizeof(myDataStructure));
```

Now I could call

```
clientSet(my_ptr, "X", "Y");
```

Does this look like it could be what I am supposed to do?

Comment: I suggest you 2 things:
1) publish some code with your question, 2) design a interface with all client related methods, make a class in dll implementing thats methods and EXPORT just one function returning that method, this way: __declspec(dllexport) client_interface* GetClientManager();

Comment: @GerardoSánchez: Unfortunately I am not allowed to change the interface, I also added some clarifications. As for code: I don't have any, yet. I'd like to understand how to do this "correctly" before I even start hacking something together.

Comment: you export C functions, but you can implement them with C++. in that case you can use all needed containers (std::map) to keep your data for each client.

Comment: How can you send a `long *` to initClient (and return a `long`) and then use one of those values as the `int` to clientSet? For sure that will fail, probably very early.

Comment: @AnatolyS: Thats a good idea, I'll keep that in mind in case it turns out I need to really keep a map or similar data set

Comment: @KevinDTimm: What I currently think: I pass a pointer to a long to the init function. The init function performs a malloc which returns a memory address. The init function writes this address to the location of the pointer passed to the init function. Since I do now have the address outside the init function (the content of the pointer address) in the main program, I can use the content to pass it to the set function.

Comment: @TomL. why do you need to malloc clientid?

Comment: I think I need to malloc some memory. The client ID could be the pointer to that memory. In this case i wouldn't need to keep track of multiple clients inside my part but this would be handled outside my responsibility. I will add some more clarification to the original question in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

You need export C functions, but you can implement them with C++. In that case you can use all needed containers and data types (std::map, std::string) to keep data for each client. As you can see there is no any malloc:

```
struct client {
  std::string a;
  std::string b;
};

std::map<long, client> clients;

extern "C" {
  long initClient(long* clientid, char* a = "", char* b = "") {
    // if you need generate clientid you can use static atomic long
    static std::atomic_long id(0);
    clients[*clientid = ++id] = client{ a, b };
    return *clientid;
  }
  long clientSet(int clientid, const char* a, const char* b) {
    clients[clientid] = client{ a, b };
    return clientid;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After careful consideration (and some discussions), we decided to go the following way:

- initClient creates a malloc'ed memory area and returns the pointer to that instance (which is then used as an int which might be a problem in the future but that is currently in discussion)
- All functions work on that malloc'ed area
- an additional endClient function was added which free's the reserved memory space.

Apparently the real issue here is using an int as storage for a pointer.